# Should I remove the trend of this data

Tags: regression, time-series, linear, trend, test-for-trend

I have time-series data. It includes a number of patients with series conditions due to car crashes. After I remove the trend, I found that some number of patients becomes negatives which is impossible. What is the problem? What is my mistake? I remove the trend because I do not want to model it as a covariate. Why? because, I read that if I do not want to model the trend as a covariate, then I can remove it. What I should do to remove the negative values?

---

**Should I remove the trend of this data? If so,**
**how can I avoid negative values when removing the trend?**

Comment: After you model it, you can add the trend back.

Comment: @kevin012 Thanks a lot for your comment. Do you mean that I can model by data and then return back the trend for it to predict the future values (regression)?

Comment: Yes, because you have a linear trend, it would not be difficult to add the trend back. If there is still negative value and if it's not serious, you may force a lower bound for your forecast.

Comment: @kevin012 can I keep the trend.

Comment: What do you mean by keeping the trend?

Comment: @kevin012 I mean can I model the data with the trend? Or can I take natural logarithm to avoid negatives?

Comment: There are some models that don't work with a linear time trend. And you better not use the log as it would destroy the linear trend.

Comment: @kevin012 Thanks a lot. You are right. So, how to remove the trend and keep the values positive at the same time. I do not know how to force a lower bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain time series methods, like ESM deal fine with trends. Others, like ARIMA don't. So in some cases the method requires you to remove it and sometimes not. I think you should focus more on why you would want to remove it or not assuming your method allows you to have it. Sometimes you want to separate out seasonality, trends etc so you can see them.

Comment: My method do not require to remove the trend. However, some researcher said removing the trend improve the model fit.

Comment: You would have to know why they believe this and if their assumptions are likely true. Obviously if you believe the actual data has a trend in it choosing the right model is important (as is true in all regression). In ESM if there is a trend you should chose an ESM model that assumes trend.